# Unable to Select C++ VSCode Debugger Environment and Configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, configuration, vscode-debugger

I am a beginner to C++ and have just downloaded VSCode. While following several online tutorials for setting up the C++ debugger, I noticed that all of them require me to click on Run -> Add Configuration from the .cpp file to be debugged, then select environment [(the tab that should come up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBHIC.png) and then select configuration [(again, the tab that should come up for selecting configuration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozyoZ.png). However, when I click on Run -> add configuration, the first thing that comes up is [(the launch.json page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ8Mj.png).

I am lost as to how exactly I can troubleshoot this situation and why the "select environment" and "select configuration" search bars might not be showing up for me (I have just installed the CodeLLDB and many other C/C++ Build & Debugger Extension Packs). Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

launch.json file (not sure why this is empty):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

    ]
}
```

tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                ".Wall",
                "-std=c++17",
                "${fileDirname}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                ".Wall",
                "-std=c++17",
                "${fileDirname}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have attempted to use this code for launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this for tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But still was unable to get the "select environment" and "select configuration" search bars to appear.

Comment: please add some links to the tutorials you are referring to.